# Php:Return a String from a function

Tags: php

The simple program is not returning the string,Please help.

```
<?php 
function returnStr() {
return "fooBar";
}
$str=returnStr();
echo $str;
}
?>
```

Comment: This is a good reason to indent code - you would've seen it if it was properly indented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a fatal error tokenizing the code due the trailing/unmatched '}' remove that and the code will work. Then spend some time thinking about why you didn't know this already

Answer (score 6):

It's a parse error:

```
$str=returnStr();
echo $str;
}                   // WHAT IS THIS BRACKET DOING HERE?
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your code. The last `}` is useless.